# How can I return widgets either in Column or ListView?

Tags: flutter

I have this code and I Want to use either ListView or Column to return some widgets of padding.

```
body: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
  if (constraints.maxWidth < 600.0) {
    return  Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        MyApp(),
      ],
    ); // phone view
  } else {
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      children: <Widget>[
        MyApp(),
      ],
    );//tablet view
  }
}),
```

I am trying to return these widgets:

padding(//something inside),
padding(//something inside),
padding(//something inside)

How do I return these to the code above?

Answer (score 0):

You can return it as a list of objects like,

```
return [
       padding(//something inside),
       padding(//something inside), 
       padding(//something inside)
];
```

Comment: But List<Padding> is not a widget